# iOS App keeps crashing

Tags: ios, crash, installation, sideloading

I do not have a paid Developer Account so I'm just using the side loading technique in Xcode to run my apps on iPhone. I've installed 3 apps like this on my iPhone and they work fine at start but after a few days they don't even open, they crash instantly. So I reinstall them again using Xcode and this process repeats quite often. Has this happened to anyone ? If yes is there some fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps installed with free developer account have expiry date of about 48 hours , after which they do not open. I do not have any official document to support this but this is what I have observed ever since I have started using free developer account.

There is nothing one can do about this.

Comment: I wish I could back you on that but from my experience one of my apps lasted a month, the other a week or so.

Comment: @RakshithGb may be you installed that app with paid account profile?

Comment: No, it was from the same free account. Is there anyway to package it to a signed ipa and install it on my personal device for free?

Comment: I thought free profiles lasted 1 week from creation, you can check their expiry date anyway

Comment: @Wain you are spot on, just created a new profile which is having expiry date of 1 week but may be if ill use it after 3-4 days it will still expire on a week from today.